# Twitter BootStrap Popover not displaying

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I'm trying to get bootstraps popover working on a glyph icon within a span, but it's just not working.

In my html:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="0" title="Offer Details" data-content="Some stuff goes here"></span>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In my JS:

```
$(document).ready(
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            placement : 'top',
            trigger: 'focus click',
        })
    })
);
```

When I click on the glyph, I can see in the console that the span gets appended with `aria-describedby="popover41686"` and when I click away it gets removed. Thus the functionality of the popover seems to be working, just that my actual popover isn't being displayed.

I implemented a similar thing with Bootstrap's tooltips prior to this and had no issues. Could it be something to do with the span, as I found info saying the tabindex needed to be set because a span isn't normally focusable?

Comment: Did you know that glyphicons have been removed in Bootstrap 4? Which version are you using? The question is tagged 3, but your code says 4. Is that all of the html in the entire BODY tag? Where is bootstrap.css being included?

Comment: Can you try to add "container: 'body'" as an option.

Comment: @ZimSystem My glyph was still showing, so I must have been loading bootstrap 3 elsewhere in my app. I removed the link to bootstrap 4 and its now working, thanks for the spot.